# 'combining' results as a node entry using xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am trying to solve a *problem*/implementation using xpath. Using code (python) is of course also possible, but I prefer to do it in xpath *if possible*

Right, say I've got a xml file that looks a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dir>
    <results>
        <entrylist>
            <entry>
                <type>document</type>
                <name>a file name 1</name>
                <date>2012-01-01</date>
                <size>65421316516</size>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <type>document</type>
                <name>a file name 2</name>
                <date>2012-01-02</date>
                <size>6542131</size>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <type>document</type>
                <name>a file name 3</name>
                <date>2012-01-03</date>
                <size>654</size>
            </entry>
        </entrylist>
    </results>
</dir>
```

*I can not change the layout of the xml*
From this xml I need to extract the name and date of each entry. I somewhat prefer them to be grouped together without the type/size in the result returned by my xpath function.

So to sum it up, I need(want) an output that looks a bit like this:

> [0]
>    | - name: a file name 1
>    | - date: 2012-01-01
>
> [1]
>    | - name: a file name 2
>    | - date: 2012-01-02
>   etc

Is this in any possible way even possible? or I am I stuck with just using a xmldocument parser in python? (using etree from lxml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you would like, but:

```py
In [1]: from lxml.etree import parse

In [2]: tree = parse('/tmp/test.xml')

In [3]: for entry in tree.xpath('/dir/results/entrylist/entry'):
   ...:     print entry.xpath('name|date')
   ...:
[<Element name at 0x2ce7d70>, <Element date at 0x2ce7dc0>]
[<Element name at 0x2ce7dc0>, <Element date at 0x2ce7c30>]
[<Element name at 0x2ce7c30>, <Element date at 0x2ce7d70>]
```

AFAIK, XPath is for selecting nodes, not combining them, so I don't think it can do all of the job for you.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help. Also, I've simplified the query inside the `for` loop; the use of the `child::` _Axis_ seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using XQuery, which is a superset of XPath, and allows you to construct new XML documents containing structured information.